# How to show percentage ratio in JSP using JSTL or jQuery?

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, jstl

I am using JSTL in my jsp page to iterate my object and then show in the table as shown below and it works fine -

```
<c:forEach items="${test.dataList}" var="m3">
    <tr>
        <th>${m3.hostName}</th>
        <td>${m3.totalCall}</td>
        <td>${m3.timeoutCount}</td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Now what I am looking to do is, I want to add percentage  of `timeoutCount` as compare to `totalCall` next to `${m3.timeoutCount}` using JSTL. Below is an example -

```
MachineA
10000
25 (0.25%)
```

But if `totalCall` is 0 then I don't want to show percentage ratio at all. Is this possible to do in JSP page using JSTL or jquery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this one:

```
<c:forEach items="${test.dataList}" var="m3">
    <tr>
        <th>${m3.hostName}</th>
        <td>${m3.totalCall}</td>
        <td>${m3.timeoutCount}
<c:if test="${m3.totalCall > 0}">
   <c:out value="%"/>
</c:if>
</td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

I haven't tested it but that should do.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. How does it divide timeoutCount with totalCall?

Comment: you can do the division like `${m3.totalCall / m3.timeoutCount}`